# How to set MouseAppearance to void?

Tags: front-end

I need to get an output graphics which does not show mouse cursor over itself. I didn't find a corresponding value in `MouseAppearance` documentation and ended up with

```
MouseAppearance[Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], Graphics[{Opacity[0.01], Point[{0, 0}]}]]
```

Is there a right way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right way w.r.t function syntax if that is what you mean. A more concise way would be an empty string:

```
MouseAppearance[Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], ""]
```

If that doesn't work on Windows try

```
MouseAppearance[Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], Spacer[0]]
```

(BTW for fun try this modified example from the docs:

```
cur = Graphics[{Red, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, 1}}], 
   Polygon[{{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {.5, 2}}], Dashing[Small], 
   Line[{{.5, 1}, {.5, 2}}]}, ImageSize -> Large];

MouseAppearance[Style["Select this text.", 36], cur, {.5, 1.5}]
```

Evaluate this at the bottom of a notebook and what you should see is that the graphic goes outside of the notebook.)

**Edit**

John Fultz has [just posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19290/is-there-a-grabhand-and-openhand-mouseappearance-in-mathematica/19390#19390) an undocumented mouse appearance "Obscure" that does what you need

```
MouseAppearance[Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], "Obscure"]
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, but on my v. 8.0.4 and WinXP your code produces a black square cursor... Am I the only one?

Comment: @faleichik I am on Mac. Try `Spacer[0]` in place of the empty string.

Comment: No luck. The same black square...

Comment: @faleichik that looks like a bug to me. Could you post a screen grab -- maybe add it to your question to show what isn't currently working in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can, somewhat more tersely, just use `Graphics@{Null}` as the second argument to `MouseAppearance`.