# Is there a "GrabHand" and "OpenHand" MouseAppearance in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, undocumented

```
MouseAppearance[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}], "LinkHand"]
```

[image: hand]

Unfortunately I cannot get a screen grab to show the link hand but it is a cartoon hand with a finger pointing. In most/many graphics packages there is also an open hand (open carton hand) and a closed hand (closed cartoon hand) used for sliding a graphics within a region.

*I realize that if I can find some open source clip art* then I can use this as a mouse appearance:

```
MouseAppearance[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}], clip art]
```

But was wondering if undocumented open hand and grab hand exists within Mathematica?

Intended usage: I have an application for sliding a graphic. I wanted to use an open hand over the graphic and grab hand/closed hand for sliding the graphic.

My reason for seeking something built in is solely aesthetic so that it matches the "LinkHand" appearance. If I cannot have a built in solution I'll look for clip art for the full set of icons -- including the link hand.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer built-in over small icon image? I don't believe there will be a slowdown.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I am assuming that if it is built in it will be aesthetically/stylistically consistent with the built in link hand. I agree that I would not expect a slowdown using clip art.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I have just looked at your link. Yesterday I wrote some code to do this but must be losing my memory. When I looked at your link my first thought was I wish I had known about this and saved myself some time. ...then I noticed that I had previously voted +1 for it!!

Comment: Mike, as the answer of John does provide a zoom icon that I was missing earlier, I've updated my [`PlotExplorer`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/89) accordingly and removed my above comment. Just for the record. Thanks for the upvote though :)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Great thread :)

Answer (score 15):

There is an undocumented "Hand" named cursor that should work on all platforms.

```
MouseAppearance[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}], "Hand"]
```

Unfortunately, there isn't anything that resembles a grabbed hand.  Here are some other undocumented ones.  Nothing here is secret, but most of it is comparatively boring and, being undocumented, is potentially subject to change in future versions.  `"Hand"` is a system cursor, but most of the rest of these are hand-drawn cursor resources bundled with Mathematica:

- `"MathEditxx"` where xx = "", 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315
- `"Crosshair"`
- `"Formatted"`
- `"Cellxx"` where xx = Select, Shade, Sound, Insert
- `"NameSelect"`
- `"SimpleWait"`
- `"FramexxRotate"` for xx = LC, RC, CT, CB, LT, RB, RT, LB
- `"MeasureGraphic"`
- `"xxGraphics"` for xx = Delete, Test, Select
- `"DragGraphicsxxy"` for xx = "", Highlight, Direct, HighlightDirect and Y = "", H, V
- `"DragSegment"`
- `"SampleStyle"`
- `"DoNothing"`
- `"Drawxx"` for xx = "", Line, Polyline, Polygon, Rectangle, Arrow, Circle, ArcCursor, Point, Freehand, Pixel
- `"Placexx"` for xx = Text, Math
- `"xxView"` for xx = Rotate, Pan, Zoom, as well as `"RotateViewVertical"`
- `"Obscure"`
- `"NetworkGraphics"`
- `"NetworkGraphicsEdit"`

You can try them all with the following:

```
cursors = {"LinkHand", "Hand", "MathEdit45", "MathEdit90", "MathEdit135", "MathEdit180", 
    "MathEdit225", "MathEdit270", "MathEdit315", "Crosshair","Formatted",
    "CellSelect", "CellShade", "CellSound", "CellInsert", "NameSelect", "SimpleWait", 
    "FrameLCRotate", "FrameRCRotate", "FrameCTRotate", "FrameCBRotate", "FrameLTRotate", 
    "FrameRBRotate", "FrameRTRotate" , "FrameLBRotate", "MeasureGraphic", "DeleteGraphics", 
    "TestGraphics", "SelectGraphics", "DragGraphics", "DragGraphicsHighlight", 
    "DragGraphicsDirect", "DragGraphicsHighlightDirect", "DragGraphicsH", 
    "DragGraphicsHighlightH", "DragGraphicsDirectH", "DragGraphicsHighlightDirectH", 
    "DragGraphicsV", "DragGraphicsHighlightV", "DragGraphicsDirectV", 
    "DragGraphicsHighlightDirectV","DragSegment", "SampleStyle", "DoNothing",
    "DrawLine", "DrawPolyline", "DrawPolygon", "DrawRectangle", "DrawArrow", "DrawCircle", 
    "DrawArcCursor", "DrawPoint", "DrawFreehand", "DrawPixel", "PlaceText", "PlaceMath",
    "RotateView", "PanView", "ZoomView", "RotateViewVertical", "Obscure", "NetworkGraphics", 
    "NetworkGraphicsEdit"};

(MouseAppearance[#, #] & /@ cursors) ~Partition~ 3 // TableForm
```

Comment: thanks John. This is a useful list.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows (Vista 64bit), you can find several hand icons in native cursor format [`CUR`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/CUR.html) in the directory `C:\Windows\Cursors`

```
 {hand1, hand2, hand3, hand4, hand5} = {Import["C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\hmove.cur"][[1]],
 Import["C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\hnwse.cur"][[1]],
 Import["C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\harrow.cur"][[1]],
 Import["C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\hcross.cur"][[1]],
 Import["C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\hnodrop.cur"][[1]]}
```

[image]

```
 MouseAppearance[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}], hand2]
```

[image]

**Update:** Mathematica cell expressions for the cursor graphics:

hand1:

```
 Cell[BoxData[ GraphicsBox[
  TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
   1:eJxTTMoPSmNiYGAo5gASQYnljkVFiZXBLECOU2VJahIzkKEAxSDB////j+JR
   PIrJwA0NDf9BeCDshGTd//8PHDgAZtPDLVDz4XbiYQ+o/bQIC2xhTq+wANmN
   bjYsLECAQLhQJczBBkHNxgewuIVq9iOzCQFa2E8KGLWfuul/oOweDPaT6oaB
   tJ+WdQAxbqBXHTQQdg8G+xkYQPUgpC7EhWlr938obsCDaeOGUftHtv3DEQMA
   AMvl3Q==
       "], {{0, 32}, {32, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction -> RGBColor],
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
  Interleaving -> True],
    Selectable -> False],
  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
  ImageSizeRaw -> {32, 32},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 32}, {0, 32}}]], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

hand2:

```
  Cell[BoxData[
GraphicsBox[
  TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
   1:eJztlVEKwjAMhof64DH0KHqEeYIN9HUwBdlbj9abxY4aLDFddaSRFQv/2nXQ
   7wtr6b7t6suqqqrr1j3q5n7o+2Y4bdzLcbid27Ub7J4ZJwHgn4XEGANc/G/M
   zw6btRa54VilZoabxYHWnKhd1AHrxLU/ccBewgFrD9ekPpRLe0n+1LeS+ZwD
   x4/sDbG9P64ZnkGc45rUOYidv1QrhT/XoST+HAfNu0CL/41D7vs41Zj7Qs3B
   Mw2JjgPP1nGYZvtI89HBs0GdjXnxeYec7Hc+qLJ5PqixYw6abOrwC/ZS8wD+
   AMqd
       "], {{0, 32}, {32, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction -> RGBColor],
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
  Interleaving -> True],
    Selectable -> False],
  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
  ImageSizeRaw -> {32, 32},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 32}, {0, 32}}]], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

hand3:

```
  Cell[BoxData[
GraphicsBox[
  TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
   1:eJxTTMoPSmNiYGAo5gASQYnljkVFiZXBLECOU2VJahIzkKEAxSDB////Dync
   0NDwH4QHym4QOHDgwH9I0I3aP5Ltp3daxOJ/uroFn/30iBdi7ac0LGD60f1C
   gv8pCgtc6RwmDgLY2NSMC2xuQLYTF6BWHkW2C2YWzG/EAGqkRXQ3gPBA2U8q
   oFZeJNcNA2k/tcshUt0w3OwnxQ20rAOIcQO96qCBsHsw2M/AAKoXG+DlMTZM
   W7v/Q3EDHkwbN4zaP7LtH44YAM543sY=
       "], {{0, 32}, {32, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction -> RGBColor],
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
  Interleaving -> True],
    Selectable -> False],
  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
  ImageSizeRaw -> {32, 32},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 32}, {0, 32}}]], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

hand4:

```
 Cell[BoxData[
GraphicsBox[
  TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
   1:eJztlUEOgjAQRSfqwmPoUfQIeAJIdGuCJoZdj9abja0yOph2WrBUFyV5pDQw
   708KZducq9MCAC5rc6rq265t6+6wMhf77npslmaw6bGTiFgoFArRKKUwlin1
   QdiX+pqDQ2uNz0e84yR+l3uODC4/d1NNix2nzsD9SgFayEW1aJ5D94zNIByv
   26hf6ZdFrsD6jOqfe3n/Pvh6pPBL60/fGM+Ww8/rhfpO5fdlCPU9xS8h7QEx
   fgD1IHcG7s6dweVOlcEivQeS+1s/4doD3uuNs7rlPMjI4x5mQGeGud1+P2Zx
   +zLkdH9m+IW78P/cAe6De2M=
       "], {{0, 32}, {32, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction -> RGBColor],
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
  Interleaving -> True],
    Selectable -> False],
  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
  ImageSizeRaw -> {32, 32},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 32}, {0, 32}}]], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

hand5:

```
  Cell[BoxData[
GraphicsBox[
  TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
   1:eJxTTMoPSmNiYGAo5gASQYnljkVFiZXBLECOU2VJahIzkKEAxSDB////Dync
   0NDwH4QHym4QOHDgwH9I0I3aP5Ltp3daxOJ/uroFn/30iBdi7ac0LGD60f1C
   gv8pCgtc6RwmDgLY2NSMC2xuQLYTF6BWHkW2C2YWzG9gAGIjYzRAjbSI7gYQ
   htkNZ0Pl0N1AbfuR/Y3LPmQxauVFDDegxwEOObrYj8M91C6HUNyAFvcoYvSw
   H4sbaBX3hNyALf/Rsg4gpvyhVx00EHYPBvsZGED1YgO8PMaGaWs3LMk14MG0
   ccOo/SPb/uGIAbULqQ4=
       "], {{0, 32}, {32, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction -> RGBColor],
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
  Interleaving -> True],
    Selectable -> False],
  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
  ImageSizeRaw -> {32, 32},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 32}, {0, 32}}]], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

Comment: FYI: this set is not present by default in Windows 7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you; i should have noted Windows Vista.

Comment: This addresses aesthetic consistency that I mentioned in a comment above as being the reason for wondering if an undocumented built in version exists. However given this appears to be limited to one windows platform I'd prefer to access open source clip art.